# AWS Glue- make sure only 1 output file is in s3 bucket

Tags: aws-glue

We have an aws glue job that copies data from rds to s3. Right now whenever this job runs, it creates a new file in our s3 bucket. How can we make sure it overwrites the old file in the bucket / deletes all files from the bucket before creating the new file ?(so we will always have one file in the bucket)
....

```
repartitioned1 = applymapping1.repartition(1)

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = repartitioned1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://our-s3-bucket-name"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, in a separate glue job, type of "python shell", use some python code with the boto3.client('s3') to delete the file. Then create a short glue workflow to run you "delete job" and then the 'spark' glue job.